# Moving from Spring 3.1 with Eclipse Gemini Blueprint to Spring 4.2.5

Tags: spring, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I have a project that used Spring 3.1 and Eclipse Gemini 1.0.2 for an OSGi project. I recently moved to Java 8 and found that Spring asm could no longer scan my classes because I was using Java 8 lambdas and that I needed to upgrade to Spring 4.x to get Java 8 support.

I upgraded to Spring 4.2.5 and am being told that Eclipse Gemini 1.0.2 will no longer work, it wants Spring 3.0 <= x < Spring 4.

It seems Gemini is dead, when I go to Eclipse, I see a download for 1.0.2 and then a milestone for 2.0.0, but no other releases.

What OSGi Blueprint container should I use if I am using Spring? My project uses Spring MVC, Spring Webflow, Spring transactions, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems the Eclipse Gemini Blueprint project is still alive.

Version 2.0 was released soon after you posted your question.

Version 2.1 was released just two months ago, and supports Spring 4.3.x.

Reference: [ECLIPSE GEMINI BLUEPRINT CHANGELOG](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gemini.blueprint/org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.git/plain/changelog.txt)

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer! I upgraded to Blueprint 2.1 and hence to Spring 4.3 after I saw your post and can now use Java 8 and Scala 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, there is no implementation today of blueprint which supports Spring 4.

- There is an official Gemini 2.0 which seem to support it (a milestone 2.0.0.M3 not released to a public repository). See [this commit](https://github.com/eclipse/gemini.blueprint/commit/ac963cca7caa31d4ee43a567a427763cccadc1b0)
- There is too an unofficial component of Aries-blueprint which seem to support Spring namespace (but not released too - or at least, I never see any documentation about it). See [ARIES-1456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1456) or [this bundle](https://github.com/apache/aries/tree/trunk/blueprint/blueprint-spring)

Personally, I am looking for a working version too, but unfortunately, blueprint/spring-dm is more or less deprecated. The Aries implementation looks like the more stable today, but I am slowly migrating my component to Declaratives-Services, and embedding Spring myself.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like maybe I should roll back to the previous Spring, do the work I actually want to get done, and plan on a project to remove Spring. Definitely have wanted to remove Spring MVC and Webflow and use Angular over websockets. What are you doing to plug your springbeans into declarative sevices?